# React hooks onSubmit render one cycle late then useEffect one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to append new onSubmit query immediately but it append one cycle later.

So I searched lots of stuffs and they all said use another useEffect then it will solved.

I use another useEffect and that printed immediately(what I really want).
But getSearch query is still late then inside of useEffect one.

How can I put getSearch function inside of useEffect?

I also tried put prop like isColor(prop) and put isColor inside of useEffect and that cause error.

Thanks for help!!

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faSearch } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import "./search.css";
import PageTitle from "./component/PageTitle";
import Cloud from "./component/Cloud";
import Loading from "./component/Loading";

//https://api.color.pizza/v1/
//data.colors[0].name

const App = () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [colorNames, setColorNames] = useState("");
    // const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
    const [cloudHex, setCloudHex] = useState("ivory");
    const [shake, setShake] = useState(false);
    // const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

    
    const search = useRef('');

    useEffect(() => {
        getColorLists();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect: ",query)
    },[query])

    const getColorLists = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(`https://api.color.pizza/v1/`);
        const data = await res.json();
        setColorNames(data);
        setIsLoading(true);
    };

    const isColor = (query) => {
        let makeUpper =
        query.search(/\s/) == -1
                ? query.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + query.slice(1)
                : query
                      .split(" ")
                      .map((i) => i.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + i.slice(1))
                      .join(" ");

        for (let i = 0; i < colorNames.colors.length; i++) {
            if (colorNames.colors[i].name == makeUpper) {
                setCloudHex(colorNames.colors[i].hex);
                setShake(false)
                return;
            } else if (i == colorNames.colors.length - 1) {
                setShake(true)
                setTimeout(() => {setShake(false)}, 200)
                return;
            }
        }
    };


    const getSearch = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setQuery(search.current.value);
        isColor();
        console.log(query)
    };

    return (
        <>
            {!isLoading ? (
                <Loading />
            ) : (
                <div className="App">
                    <div className="app-wrap">
                        <PageTitle />
                        <div className="search-wrap">
                            <form onSubmit={getSearch} className="search-form">
                                <input
                                    className="search-bar"
                                    type="text"
                                    ref={search}
                                />
                                <button type="submit" className="search-button">
                                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                                        icon={faSearch}
                                        className="search"
                                    />
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <Cloud cloudhex={cloudHex} shake={shake} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Cloud.js

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faCloud } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import './cloud.css';

const Cloud = ({cloudhex, shake}) => {
    return (
        <div className={`cloud-wrap ${ shake ? "shake-cloud":''}`}>
            <span className="cloudhexname">{cloudhex}</span>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCloud} className="cloud" style={{color:`${cloudhex}`}} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Cloud;
```

Comment: getColorLists is an async function, maybe that's why? it must be running the first time for sure tho

Comment: First useEffect is okay. Problem is second one.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more data as to what actually happens and how you see that it does not get appended. Because there seems to be initially nothing wrong with the `getSearch` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a useRef to keep the reference for your function.

Please check if you really need to do this.

```
const App = () => {
    
 const search_ref = React.useRef(null);
    
      React.useEffect(()=>{
        const getSearch = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            setQuery(search.current.value);
            isColor();
            console.log(query)
        };
        console.log("Updating search_ref...");
        search_ref.current = getSearch;
      },[]);
    
      return(
        <form onSubmit={() => search_ref.current} className="search-form">
        
      </form>
      );
    }
```